# Multi-parameter mapping with Three20 and TTURLMap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I'm following [this](http://www.three20.info/ui/navigation) tutorial and declare the following mappings in my app delegate:

```
[map from:@"x://profile/(initWithId:)/(name:)" toViewController:[ProfileViewController class]];
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

In `ProfileViewController.m` I implement the `- (id)initWithId:(int)anIdentifier name:(NSString *)name` selector to handle such mapping. I suppose opening URLs like `x://profile/1/John Doe` would invoke `[[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithId:1 name:@"John Doe"]`, however, this seems not to be the case. The default `TTWebController` class gets called every time I open said URL.

Using single parameter, i.e something like `x://profile/(initWithId:)` does the right thing, which is to call `[[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithId:1]`.

Did I miss something here? How to use multi-parameter mapping with Three20 and TTURLMap?

Comment: Do you need to use toViewController: in order to pass data, or can you use toModalViewController: as well? Because I'm using toModalViewController: and passing some data, and while the initWithId: method I'm using gets called, it doesn't actually open the view for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is the that "x://profile/1/John Doe" isn't properly formatted as a URL. when you build the URL, try something like:

```
NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x://profile/%d/%@", 1,
                 [@".." stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

enjoy!

/mtr