# TTNavigator not correctly opening TTURLMap when passing parameters

Tags: ios4, three20, ttnavigator

I'm trying to pass parameters via Three20 for iOS in a way similar to this question: [Multi-parameter mapping with Three20 and TTURLMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182585/multi-parameter-mapping-with-three20-and-tturlmap)

However, I'm running into an issue that question doesn't address. My mapping is currently set up as

```
    [map from:@"sb://launcher/(initWithAccount:)" toModalViewController:[AccountOverviewViewController class] transition:0];
```

To get there, I am calling:

```
    NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sb://launcher/%@", [@"hey" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:URL] applyAnimated:YES]];
```

Then, in AccountOverviewViewController, I have

```
- (void)initWithAccount:(NSString *)name {
NSLog(name);
```

}

to make sure I'm getting the right value (which I am) as Console.app is outputting "hey". All that is working fine except for one thing, AccountOverviewViewController never shows up! The initWithAccount: method inside of it is called, but it never displays itself on the screen. Am I missing a step here to get the controller to get the parameter AND show itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `initWithAccount:(NSString*)name` method is wrong. It should read `- (id)initWithAccount:(NSString*)name` and it should return self. TTNavigator uses this return value (it's a UIViewController descendant) and pushes it to the navigation controller. As you are not returning anything, it's pure luck, that the app doesn't crash, but merely displays nothing.

The pattern to use for **any** method that begins with init in Cocoa Touch is:

```
- (id) initWithSomething:(id)something {
    if (self = [<designated initializer>]) {
        //Do something here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

The first line depends on which class you are subclassing from. You would always want to invoke the **designated initializer**. So given you're subclassing UIViewController or TTViewController if would be `[self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
NSString *strTTURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tt://PhotoDetail/%@",photoID];
TTURLAction *urlAction=[[[TTURLAction alloc] initWithURLPath:strTTURL] autorelease];
urlAction.animated=YES;
[[TTNavigator navigator]openURLAction:urlAction];
```